# Make AutoMapper automatically map prefixed properties

Tags: c#, automapper

I want AutoMapper to map automatically Members like this:

```
class Model 
{
    public int ModelId { get; set; }
}

class ModelDto 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Here, I would do a

```
CreateMap<Model, ModelDTO>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Id, e => e.MapFrom(x => x.ModelId)
```

But, how could I make AutoMapper do the mapping automatically? Most of my classes are like that. The Primary key is in the form: ClassName + "Id".

### Edit

I've tried with this, but it doesn't work:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(exp =>
        {
            exp.CreateMap<User, UserDto>();
            exp.ForAllPropertyMaps(map => map.DestinationProperty.Name.Equals("Id"), (map, expression) => expression.MapFrom(map.SourceType.Name + "Id"));
        });


        var user = new User() { UserId = 34};
        var dto = Mapper.Map<UserDto>(user);
    }
}

public class UserDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: http://automapperdocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Configuration.html?highlight=prefix#recognizing-pre-postfixes

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu my prefixes aren't constant. The examples in there are for constant values.

Comment: Then you need to apply the MapFroms with ForAllPropertyMaps or ForAllMaps.

Comment: Could you, please, provide a sample? Thanks :)

Comment: No, you'll have to google it.

Comment: Sorry, but I haven't found more than a few examples that don't fit my needs and I don't know how to apply. Maybe you can share a sample, or give a link to the docs where this usage is clarified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the code looks reasonable, but it doesn't work. That's because it runs after the property maps are computed. And there are none in this case, because the names don't match. My bad :) Try

```cs
exp.ForAllMaps((typeMap, mappingExpression) => 
    mappingExpression.ForMember("Id", o=>o.MapFrom(typeMap.SourceType.Name + "Id"))
);
```