# AutoMapper automatically map prefixed properties

Tags: automapper

I want AutoMapper to map automatically Members like this:

```
class Model { 
public int MDId { get; set; } 
public int MDName { get; set; } 
}

class ModelDto {
 public int Id { get; set; } 
 public int Name { get; set; } 
}
```

Here, I would do a

```
CreateMap<Model, ModelDTO>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Id, e => e.MapFrom(x => x.MDId )
    .ForMember(x => x.Id, e => e.MapFrom(x => x.MDName )
```

but,Most of my classes are like that,My Model have prefix in Database,
DTO haven't;And classes prefix not only 'MD', all different in my project

how could I make AutoMapper do the mapping automatically? thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47527543/make-automapper-automatically-map-prefixed-properties?noredirect=1#comment82020725_47527543

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu thanks